# Rounding to 2 decimal places in Python

Tags: python

This isn't a duplicate because I have checked everything before this post on this site. I think I have managed to do the first two bullet points. The first one I will do through a string but I am willing to change that if you know another way. The 2nd one is using comma seperators for the $'s. So I will use a float but once again am willing to change if better way is found. [image: This is the task I have to complete]

But I am stuck.
And the "print("%.2f") % str) is something I found but I need work on rounding to two decimal spaces and the last bullet point.

Code:

```
import random


def random_number():
    random_dollars = random.uniform(1.00, 10000.00)
    print(round(random_dollars, 2))
    print("%.2f") % str


print(random_number())
```

Shell:

```
C:\Users\jacke\PycharmProjects\ASLevelHomeworkWeek18\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py 6567.62 Traceback (most recent call last): %.2f File 

C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py", line 10, in <module> print(random_number()) File

C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py", line 7, in random_number print("%.2f") % str TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'type' Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: If have not told us where you are stuck.  What error message are you getting, and what incorrect results? 
You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: C:\Users\jacke\PycharmProjects\ASLevelHomeworkWeek18\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py
6567.62
Traceback (most recent call last):
%.2f
  File "C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(random_number())
  File "C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18/ASLevelHomeworkWeek18.py", line 7, in random_number
    print("%.2f") % str
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'type'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please edit that information into your question.

Comment: Please take the time to include the requirements as text and not image in your question and add the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can format currency like this:

```
 def random_number():
    random_dollars = random.uniform(1, 10000)
    result = '$ {:0>9}'.format('{:,.2f}'.format(random_dollars))
    print(result)
```

`{:0>10}` means: pad string left to width 9 with 0's.
`{:,.2f}` rounds to two decimal places (`.2f`) and adds a comma as thousands-separator.

Just one side note: by using `random.uniform(1, 10000)` most of your numbers will be large (>1000), if you want to test your script with small amounts you could use `random_dollars = 10**random.uniform(0, 4)` instead:

```
 def random_number():
    random_dollars = 10**random.uniform(0, 4)
    result = '$ {:0>9}'.format('{:,.2f}'.format(random_dollars))
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are saying you want to round a number to 2 decimal places. Here is how I would do it.

```
import random


def random_number():
    random_dollars = random.uniform(1, 10000)
    split = str(random_dollars).split(".")
    if (len(split) == 2 ):
      if (len(split[1]) == 1 ):# checks if 1 digit after decimal place
         answer = split[0] + ".0"
      split[1] = str(int(int(split[1]) / (10 ** (len(split[1]) - 3) )))
      # Gets 3 decimal places

      if int(split[1][-1:]) => 5: #Checks if last digit is above or equal to 5
        split[1] = int(split[1][:-1])
        split[1] += 1

      else:
        split[1] = int(split[1][:-1])
      answer = split[0] + '.' + str(split[1])

    else:
      answer = split[0] + ".00"
    print(answer)

random_number()
```

This makes it so if the random number is somehow 100 it will add 2 zeros. If the number is like 100.1 it will add one zero. It will also round it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def random_number():
    random_dollars = random.uniform (1.00, 10000.00)
    n = round(random_dollars,2)

    bd, d = str(n).split('.')

    if len(d) == 1:
        n = bd + "." + d + '0'
        return n

    else:
        return n




for i in range(1, 20):

 print(random_number())

7340.55
7482.70
3956.81
3044.50
4108.57
4864.90
235.00
9831.98
960.97
1172.28
5221.31
3663.50
5410.50
3448.52
8288.13
293.48
1390.68
9216.15
6493.65
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you have to put the % directly after the string and you have to put a real variable there, not the type `str`

from the last line of your error message you can see that the problem is the % operator. You can also see that it tried to do the operation with two objects of types 'NoneType' and 'type'. Since you put the entire print statement in front of the % and print returns `None` (which is of type `NoneType`), the first operand is of type `NoneType`. then, the second operand is the type `str`, which is, as just said, a `type`. You can fix this by moving the % operator after the string and replacing `str` with your variable `random_dollars` since that is what you want to insert into the string.

```py
import random


def random_number():
    random_dollars = random.uniform(1.00, 10000.00)
    print(round(random_dollars, 2))
    # this:
    print("%.2f" % random_dollars)


print(random_number())
```